# Left with gray overlay when the edit got approved before I can edit

Tags: discussion, bug

I was viewing a question on the main site and saw some improvements that I can do to that question. There was already a pending edit to that question so I decided to improve the edit instead.

But it seems like while the edit page was opening for me, that edit got approved and I was left with a grey overlay which didn't get dismissed until I clicked on the screen.

Below is the screenshot for the same.

[image]

Comment: race condition. just refresh the page?

Comment: refreshing did helped but can this be avoided ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's bad luck, so should refresh the page:

[image]

Then it will turn back to normal light,

But see if it got approved or like your improved one :-),

Same time is bad luck :D